# Paypal expres checkout is not sending back the posted data

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

in my laravel application i am sending the the data to the postman like below :

```
array:8 [▼
  "items" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:4 [▼
      "name" => "PWN Netherlands: Building a D&I foundation through mentoring, coaching & sponsorship"
      "price" => 122222
      "qty" => 1
      "event_id" => 1
    ]
  ]
  "return_url" => "http://localhost:8000/paypal/ec-checkout-success"
  "invoice_id" => "_6"
  "item_number" => 22
  "custom" => 33
  "invoice_description" => "PWN Netherlands: Building a D&I foundation through mentoring, coaching & sponsorship"
  "cancel_url" => "http://localhost:8000"
  "total" => 122222
]
```

so i am sending the `item_number` and `custom` field but after payment what i get it just `token` and `playerId` like below :

```
array:2 [▼
  "token" => "EC-4DA935906T0704531"
  "PayerID" => "QQN222QZK25CA"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

After a redirect to PayPal and payer approval, that is all you are going to get back in the return URL's parameters.

If you've integrated the old classic NVP API, the call to then get the details (if you don't have them stored in your server's session) is GetExpressCheckoutDetails.

Also, there will be no payment until you execute it. The call to do so is DoExpressCheckoutPayment.

---

This is a very old API you seem to be integrating, so the recommendation would be to switch to something current, such as 'Create Order' and 'Capture Order' as [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). Those should be two routes on your server which return JSON, which you can then pair with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: hi , i am using this package for integeration with laravel https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal

Comment: how can i understand that its a new way to integerate or the old one

Comment: Look at the API calls and read their documentation. As I said, what you are using appears to be old.